# Thought experiment - is there a possibility of never experiencing a particular outcome?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is a thought experiment I have.

Say we flip a unique coin where we have a 99.99999999999% chance of it landing on heads, and a .000000000001% chance of it landing on tails (the two possibilities equal to 100%).

And say we have an *infinite* number of coins flipped all at once (and only one time).

Is it possible that none of the trials will experience the coin land on tails?

Comment: You are talking about "possibility" and "probability."  They are similar, but not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! In fact, this would be possible with a fair coin already. In fact, it would be possible with a coin that is largely biased to come up with tails: one that has a 99.99999999999% chance of it landing on tails, and a .000000000001% chance of it landing on heads: it is *always* possible  that you get no tails at all.

But, the probability of that would be infinitely small. In fact, mathematically, it would just be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It will happen infinitely often.